# Change props value

Tags: reactjs

So I basically have this `Home` component that has a `SearchForm` component and a `PostBox` component that display the today's data from API.

```
var Home = React.createClass({
  handleSubmitSearch: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // change the URL
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="home">
        <SearchForm
          onSubmitSearch={this.handleSubmitSearch} />
        <PostBox
          url="http://localhost:3000/posts/today"
          pollInterval={2000} />
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

The thing is, when the submit button in `SearchForm` is triggered, I want to basically show the result into `PostBox` by sending a request to another API like `http://localhost:3000/posts/search/query` instead of showing today's data.
My question is, how can I change the url props on `PostBox` changed by `handleSubmitSearch()`?

Comment: You don't change `props`. A components `props` should be treated as immutable. If a component needs to store data that can change, use `state` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would put the `url` to the state and change it while submitting the form.

```
var Home = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {url: 'http://localhost:3000/posts/today'};
  },
  handleSubmitSearch: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = ''; // TODO: get value that you want
    this.setState({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/posts/' + value,
    });
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="home">
        <SearchForm
          onSubmitSearch={this.handleSubmitSearch} />
        <PostBox
          url={this.state.url}
          pollInterval={2000} />
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```